# If I set assumevalid=0 after syncing the blockchain will Bitcoin Core go back and validate historical blocks?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, signature, transaction-verification, assume-valid

I originally synced my node using the Bitcoin Core default `assumevalid` value. If I set `-assumevalid=0` in bitcoin.conf and restart my node, will my node go back and validate historical blocks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it won't.

That's also not possible without rebuilding the UTXO set from scratch, as the unspent outputs being spent need to be known to validate spends against.

If you want to force a revalidation from scratch, start with `-reindex-chainstate`. This will blow away the UTXO set, and recreate it from the blocks on disk, and revalidate everything in the process (including all signatures, if `-assumevalid=0` is set).